# Extract email field with regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to extract the "email" with this code

```
const regex3 = /Email',\r\n      value: '([^']*)',/gm;
var content3 = fs.readFileSync('message.txt')
let m3;

while ((m3 = regex3.exec(content)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m3.index === regex3.lastIndex) {
        regex3.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m3.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        fs.appendFileSync('messagematch.txt', m3[1] + '\n');
    });
}
```

From this file

```
 },
MessageEmbedField {
  embed: [Circular *2],
  name: 'Email',
  value: 'user@gmail.com',
  inline: true
},
MessageE
```

The regex code works on notepad, but doesn't on my script.. what I'm missing?

Comment: FYI - a useful tool for debugging any regex is regex101.com. Here's your code in that tool: https://regex101.com/r/b0Lhs1/2. And here's a fixed version: https://regex101.com/r/fax1Up/3/

Comment: I wonder if there's a way that you can use a library to parse the input file into a JS object, kind of like JSON.parse except for whatever format you're reading.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing your regex in a few ways to make it more robust and fault tolerant.

First, include the initial single-quote in email to avoid accidentally catching other fields where someone may have put the word "Email" as a value.

Second, use `\r?\n` to capture both Windows and Unix-style line endings.  I suspect this may be a large part of your issue, but can't be sure.

Third, use `\s+` instead of specifically including a number of spaces.  This will help to avoid problems caused by minor formatting changes.

The final regex would look like this:

```
const regex = /'Email',\r?\n\s+value: '([^']*)',/gm
```

Comment: Or just leave the line break out altogether since `\s` will match that as well.

Comment: yes, but if you specifically want to make sure there is a line break between the two pieces, you might be better leaving it in.

Answer (score 1):

> what I'm missing?

- You use `\r\n` to match a Windows style line break but you can make the `\r` optional to also match a Unix style. See [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html#linebreak) about line break characters.
- In your code you specify `var content3` but you use it like `regex3.exec(content)`
- Also the number of spaces in the question for the pattern and the examples data are different

---

You could use `\s+` instead of hardcoding the number of spaces but `\s` can also match a newline.

If you want to match whitespaces without a newline you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^\S\r\n]` to match any char except a non whitespace char and a newline.

```
'Email',\r?\n[^\S\r\n]+value:[^\S\r\n]+'([^\s@']+@[^\s@']+)'
```

- `'Email',` Match literally
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `[^\S\r\n]+` Match 1+ whitespace chars except newlines
- `value:` Match literally
- `[^\S\r\n]+'` Match 1+ whitespace chars except newlines and `'`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `([^\s@']+@[^\s@']+'` Match an email like format
- `)'` Close group 1 and match `'`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPJGMg/1)

```js
const regex3 = /'Email',\r?\n[^\S\r\n]+value:[^\S\r\n]+'([^\s@']+@[^\s@']+)'/g;
var content3 = ` },
MessageEmbedField {
  embed: [Circular *2],
  name: 'Email',
  value: 'user@gmail.com',
  inline: true
},
MessageE `;
let m3;

while ((m3 = regex3.exec(content3)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m3.index === regex3.lastIndex) {
    regex3.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m3[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, try your expression on `s` (single line) mode:

```
/Email'\s*,\s*value:\s*'([^'\r\n]*)'/gs
```

#### Test

```js
const regex = /Email'\s*,\s*value:\s*'([^'\r\n]*)'/gs;
const str = ` },
MessageEmbedField {
  embed: [Circular *2],
  name: 'Email',
  value: 'user@gmail.com',
  inline: true
},
MessageE `;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/FblpTA/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/FblpTA/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```js
var test = `
    },
    MessageEmbedField {
      embed: [Circular *2],
      name: 'Email',
      value: 'user@gmail.com',
      inline: true
    },
    Message
`;

var myregexp = /name: 'Email',\s+value: '(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b)',/img;
var match = myregexp.exec(test);
console.log(match[1]);
```

---

The regex above matches **valid email addresses only**, if you want to match anything (as it was), use:

```
var myregexp = /name: 'Email',\s+value: '([^']*)',/img;
```

---

[Regex Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/MvxGgm/1)

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)